# Really impossible to run animated GIF in async threads?

Tags: c#, animation, backgroundworker, gif

I want to run long lasting methods, even containing time consuming dlls, while a Spinner GIF is rotating.

OK, the most accepted solution is to run these methods in a BackgroundWorker while the GIF is shown in the main thread and I have already done, successfully, it but… but I am still curious to know if it is really impossible to do do the other way round !

This would simplify the calls to those methods, especially if they have arguments and return values, avoid the use of Invoke if they contain Labels to show the working progress, etc…

I have spent quite a lot of time browsing the Web but all the suggested solutions don’t work for me: as soon as the program calls my methods the Spinner stops rotating and resume working only when the methods end.

Ciao and thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: You cannot do UI work on a non-UI thread, so yes, it **really** is impossible. It's completely unrelated to GIFs too.

Comment: Also, I would doubt anyone linking to that Code Project, since it says "In C#, every object has its own thread and ..." which is factually incorrect (and couldn't be farther from reality).

Comment: I strongly suspected that it was impossible but following the Einstein sentence “Everyone knew it was impossible, until a fool who didn't know came along and did it” I thought it was worth asking.

Comment: @FrancoLanguasco I suggest you remove the link to codeproject (which is terribly wrong "In C#, every object has its own thread and ...") and post your own code.

Answer (score -1):

DONE!!

Thanks to the Camilo Terevinto sentence “You cannot do UI work on a non-UI thread” I asked myself if it was not possible to create the PictureBox that holds my spinning GIF in another thread and…

I created a new borderless Form (named frmSpinner) with inside a PictureBox running the Spinner.gif.

Then I used, in the main Form with the long running methods, a BackgroundWorker that, in the DoWork event, has a frmSpinner.Show().

Now the Spinner rotates endless without interrupting and resuming.

I have still to solve the problem how to place the Spinner Form on the right position on the main Form but, with the help of the PointToScreen method, it shouldn’t be to difficult.

Ciao and thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

Dealing explicitly with threads in a WPF/c# project is not canonical, unless you have something very specific to do, using Tasks is the modern way.

You can have a background task, started with for instance:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    // blocking methods running outside UI thread
    var newPropValue = //... update a UI property
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        //Running in UI thread.
        PropValue = newPropValue;
    });
});
```

With this pattern you can remove all the heavy/blocking work from the UI thread and have a flowing UI experience.

Comment: Sorry, I am rather new with C# coding, but I can't understand which property of my lazy PictureBox I have to update to convince it running the Spinner without interruptions.
But it is very likely that I have completely misunderstood your answer, unless you are suggesting me to run in a separated task the long lasting methods.

Comment: The Task.Run will execute the lambda function outside the UI thread, but the dispatcher will allow you to execute/update inside the UI thread in a very simple manner (you can't update a UI object/property from the lambda, only with the dispatcher). It works for any property of any object that is used in the UI. Anything that is blocking should run in the task, outside de dispatcher. So, just use it the way you need.

Comment: I want to give a try to your code but I get a compiler error at Application.Current; browsing the Web it looks like this is WPF specific; someone suggested to add a reference to the PresentationFramework, I did it but no luck.
Any tip? Thanks.

Comment: @FrancoLanguasco Make sure you have a WPF project/library, it should be painless; note that there is no `Application.Current` in unit tests projects. Indeed you need to add reference to the assembly PresentationFramework and PresentationCore (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.presentationsource?view=net-5.0).